How can I change the value in ADC_DR using the STM32_ADC class from the Renode monitor?
I'm writing firmware for a STM32F446re and I'm in the process of writing test cases for it using Renode. I'm using the Analog.STM32_ADC class in Renode to mock input values going into the ADC of the microcontroller.
# configuration in stm42f4xx.repl

adc1: Analog.STM32_ADC @ sysbus 0x40012000
    IRQ -> nvic@18

However, I find I'm not able to change the value in the ADC_DR register through the Renode monitor, thus meaning my firmware is not reading in any values from the mock ADC.
I have tried using the WriteDoubleWord command to write to the ADC_DR register directly, but it is read-only and this did not work. Additionally, the WriteDefault command is not available in the Analog.STM32_ADC class, only in classes for other specific STM32 models.
If you could please tell me how I can change the value that the ADC reads it would be highly appreciated.

On the STM32F446re:

the 0th bit of the CR2 register must be high (This enables the ADC)
use the FeedSample command to write to ADC channel corresponding with the configuration of your firmware
After each FeedSample command, set the 30th bit of CR2 high (this will tell the ADC to update)

Commands for use in Renode monitor:
adc1 WriteDoubleWord 0x08 0x40000401 // setup

adc1 FeedSample 0xFF 0  // call these two lines for each change to ADC input. 0xFF is the value to mock in the ADC, 0 is the channel number of the ADC
adc1 WriteDoubleWord 0x08 0x40000401

